# Android move app to sd

Tags: android

Actually I want to find that what kind of items that are involved when we move the app to sd card? I have tried to search, but all the answer point me to "how to move app to sd" but actually I just want to know what items been move to sd and what items are left. I can see that there is still some memory left (in internal memory) when I move the app to sd. I am just curious what are the things left ? Where actually the app move to (in which part of the sd card)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Good Question!

Let me explain you with an example package say "com.example.app"

Now, when a app is installed for the first time, a new folder will be created by the name

> /data/com.example.app

Inside this will contain all the app private data.

Similary, the APK itself is contained in

> /data/app/com.example.app-1.apk

Now, when we move application to external storage, the following happens.

- It will **not** be moved to /mnt/sdcard/ partition
- Android will create a new folder under /mnt/asec partiton called `/mnt/asec/com.example.app`. You can reach this path using any File Manager apps as it has *rw* permissions
- It will create a copy of libs directory if any and move all the files, databases here.
- It will also copy the APK from "/data/app/com.example.app-1.apk" to `/mnt/asec/com.example.app/com.example.app-1.apk`

In this way, `/data` partition space will be saved and can be reused for other apps. This is a good trick to use when phone gets low on /data storage to move apps to external storage.

Comment: Thank your very detail answer. I don't understand that if it create partition in /mnt/asec, it still use the internal memory right? It does not even go into /mnt/sdcard, why? From your answer, it seem like all the items has been moved out, what actually left in the internal memory? because we still can see that few kilobyte (more or less) of data still retain in internal memory.

Comment: Android partitions its storage into a number of sub-partitions. Try observing the /proc/partitions using adb. so /data and /mnt fall into seperate partitions. So /mnt/asec is not internal memory. Secondly why it does not go to /mnt/sdcard/ is a Android design choice. It can very well go there as well if Android OS wants it to. Also a few KB of data is seen in internal memory after moving because libraries and cache is left behind, there is also an option of "Move to Internal Storage". So it is a place holder when stuff needs to be moved back again :)

Comment: Just type "mount" and you can see all the mounted partitions:   /mnt/asec is mounted on tmpfs, which in turned is mounted on /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure - see:   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549489/mount-an-sd-card-manually-from-adb-shell-in-android   and this:     http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25439/app-cant-be-moved-to-sd-card